# Render colors do not match the reference picture

Tags: color

[image][image]I have come across this problem that I am trying to make an exact model of a product by a client and their demand is to have an exact rose gold color (golden color with pinkish hue) for their product. But when I give the color using eyedropper tool from the reference image, the color turns out to be quite different from what it looks like in the  original photo. Can someone please help me? I need to deliver the product pretty soon. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X35KD.png)

Comment: Dropper takes the color of a pixel not of an area so its color will never be the same

Comment: Can you show screenshots of your configurations and how is your model made, if they are materials or textures, do you know the technique of faking reflections?

Comment: No I don't know how to fake reflections. Can you please tell me? Yes I can show you the screen shots.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the color is just in the material, the rendered image is affected by lighting/reflections. I would recommend going into the rendered preview mode and just tweaking the color/comparing the render to what you need until it matches up.

Comment: inefficient, delayed and does not get an optimal result